# Bootstrap - Using Push/Pull with col-12?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I've only just discovered Push/Pull with Bootstrap, I can see that you can re-order the columns for different screen sizes as so:-

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-md-push-0 col-xs-push-4">1</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-md-pull-0 col-xs-pull-4">2</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">3</div>
```

Which works fine, in the above example 2 comes before 1 on smaller screens.

What about if I wanted the sm columns to be 12? How does this work then? I've tried:-

```
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-md-push-0 col-xs-12 col-xs-push-12">1</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-md-pull-0 col-xs-12 col-xs-pull-12">2</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">3</div>
```

but 1 and 2 disappear on smaller screen sizes now?

So basically I am wanting to achieve:-

```
<div class="col-sm-12">2</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">1</div>
<div class="col-sm-12">3</div>
```

for smaller devices if that makes sense?

Here is a [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/77jjbdkg/) - thanks in advance!

Comment: The idea is that you want to only define column class (`col-`) if you want to divide the row.  Otherwise, it will default to 12 columns for smaller viewports.  `<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">3</div>` is the same as `<div class="col-md-4">3</div>`.  Also, be sure to wrap your columns in a `row` and your rows in a `container` or `container-fluid`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You reverse things! You write your base code to be 2,1,3 then you push pull it until it looks the way you want it on a bigger screen.

That's the whole mobile *first* thing.

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-md-push-4">2</div> <!-- Push Column -->
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-md-pull-4">1</div> <!-- Pull Column -->
  <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-4">3</div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/uouvmybm/1/)

This breaks above `md` but you get the idea

Comment: It breaks above `md` because you have two pulls.  I've updated the fiddle for you:  https://jsfiddle.net/uouvmybm/2/